# Extracting an archive entry would create a file that is outside the specified destination directory

Tags: c#, jar, extract, unzip

When trying to extract a .jar file, I keep getting:

> Extracting an archive entry would create a file that is outside the specified destination directory

Can anyone help me? Here is my code:

```
try
{
    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(jarLocationTXT.Text, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        archive.ExtractToDirectory(@"C:\Users\Neglekt\Monix Software\MCMI\CurExtract\");
    } 
}
catch (IOException ExtrEx)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ExtrEx.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("An error occured while processing your data! \n Error code: E:002", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875102(v=vs.110).aspx) says an exception like that is thrown when `For example, the entry name contains parent directory accessors.` like `..`. It doesn't seem like there is a way to bypass that check, so an option would be to roll your own extraction method, either with a static or an extension method.

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more, I don't completely understand. Do you mean if a file name/extension is `..` Ok, that helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If an extra \ is used at the beginning of the file path when creating the ZipArchiveEntry, ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory will think that the file path is located outside of the zip file.

ok: ZipArchiveEntry.CreateEntry("folder\file.ext");

not ok: ZipArchiveEntry.CreateEntry("\folder\file.ext");
When the zip package is opened in something like 7zip, the file path is incorrect and looks something like _\folder\file.ext in the graphical user interface.

Answer (score 2):

`ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` fails if the zip contains an empty root `/`

Use `ZipFileEx.ExtractToDirectory` below instead:

```
namespace System.IO.Compression {
  public static class ZipFileEx {
    public static void ExtractToDirectory(string sourceArchiveFileName, string destinationDirectoryName) =>
    ExtractToDirectory(sourceArchiveFileName, destinationDirectoryName, entryNameEncoding: null, overwriteFiles: false);

    public static void ExtractToDirectory(string sourceArchiveFileName, string destinationDirectoryName, bool overwriteFiles) =>
        ExtractToDirectory(sourceArchiveFileName, destinationDirectoryName, entryNameEncoding: null, overwriteFiles: overwriteFiles);

    public static void ExtractToDirectory(string sourceArchiveFileName, string destinationDirectoryName, Encoding? entryNameEncoding) =>
        ExtractToDirectory(sourceArchiveFileName, destinationDirectoryName, entryNameEncoding: entryNameEncoding, overwriteFiles: false);

    public static void ExtractToDirectory(string sourceArchiveFileName, string destinationDirectoryName, Encoding? entryNameEncoding, bool overwriteFiles)
    {
      ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(sourceArchiveFileName);
      ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(destinationDirectoryName);

      using ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(sourceArchiveFileName, ZipArchiveMode.Read, entryNameEncoding);

      foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries) {
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectoryName);
        string destinationDirectoryFullPath = di.FullName;
        if (!destinationDirectoryFullPath.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)) {
          char sep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
          destinationDirectoryFullPath = string.Concat(destinationDirectoryFullPath, new ReadOnlySpan<char>(in sep));
        }

        string entryFullName = entry.FullName;
        if (entryFullName.Length > 0 && entryFullName[0] == '/') entryFullName = entryFullName[1..]; // remove leading root

        string fileDestinationPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryFullPath, entryFullName.Replace('\0', '_')));

        var IsCaseSensitive = !(OperatingSystem.IsWindows() || OperatingSystem.IsMacOS() || OperatingSystem.IsIOS() || OperatingSystem.IsTvOS() || OperatingSystem.IsWatchOS());
        var stringComparison = IsCaseSensitive ? StringComparison.Ordinal : StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

        if (!fileDestinationPath.StartsWith(destinationDirectoryFullPath,stringComparison)) throw new IOException(@"Extracting Zip entry would have resulted in a file outside the specified destination directory.");

        if (Path.GetFileName(fileDestinationPath).Length == 0) {
          if (entry.Length != 0) throw new IOException(@"Zip entry name ends in directory separator character but contains data.");
          Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDestinationPath);

        } else {
          Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDestinationPath)!);
          entry.ExtractToFile(fileDestinationPath, overwrite: overwriteFiles);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above is an exact copy of `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` except for the line that checks for `entryFullName[0] == '/'`

Comment: Thanks I'm interested what tweaking ?

Comment: Thanks can you show the edited code for 'I added one more check for every fullName's first char' please ?

Comment: OK merged that in

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875102%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says an exception like that is thrown when:

> For example, the entry name contains parent directory accessors.

A parent directory accesor is for example `..`. When you are at the command prompt and you type `cd ..`, you are telling the *change directory* (`cd`) program to go to the parent directory, that's what `..` means. So the exception is thrown because an entry in the zip file contains that a reference to some parent directory.

It doesn't seem like there is a way to bypass that check when using the `ExtractToDirectory`, so an option would be to roll your own extraction method, either with a static or an extension method. What I mean by that is creating a method of your own that:

1. Takes the path to the zip file and destination directory
2. Opens the file in a `ZipArchive`.
3. Iterates through its [`Entries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.entries%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
4. Extracts each [`ZipArchiveEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to a file using the destination directory provided and the relative path from the entry.